# R. Sample rows following conditions (at random within a range of values; fixed within another range of values)

Tags: r, sample

I have a dataframe A like this one:

```
SNP X Y
rs1 5 aa
rs2 1 bb
rs3 6 aa
rs4 2 bb
rs7 11 ft
rs8 3 hg
rs9 1.2 ff
rs10 2.2 cc
rs11 2.2 yh
rs362 3.2 hyu
```

Using R, I want to sample rows following 2 conditions: (1) keep all rows with values in X >= 5; (2) sample at random without replacement 2 rows with X > 0 and X < 5. I would get something like this:

```
SNP X Y
rs1 5 aa
rs2 1 bb
rs3 6 aa
rs7 11 ft
rs9 1.2 ff
rs362 3.2 hyu
```

I am trying something like:

```
A.1 = A[A$X >= 5,]
B.2 = A[sample(nrow(A), 2), ]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  In the second case, you may need `A1 <- subset(A, X >0 & X < 5); A1[sample(nrow(A1), 2),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `which` function:

```
set.seed(1) # reproducible
d[c(which(d$X >= 5), sample(which(d$X > 0 & d$X < 5), 2)),]

  SNP    X  Y
1 rs1  5.0 aa
3 rs3  6.0 aa
5 rs7 11.0 ft
2 rs2  1.0 bb
7 rs9  1.2 ff
```

`which(d$X >= 5)` finds the rows in your data where `X >= 5`. Then, we find the rows where `X > 0 & X < 5` using `which` again, and `sample` 2 from those rows. We then concatenate these two vectors of row indexes together.

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(SNP = c("rs1", "rs2", "rs3", "rs4", "rs7", "rs8", 
                            "rs9", "rs10", "rs11", "rs362"), 
                    X = c(5, 1, 6, 2, 11, 3, 1.2, 
                          2.2, 2.2, 3.2),
                    Y = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "bb", "ft", "hg", "ff", 
                          "cc", "yh", "hyu")), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)

A.1 <- A %>% filter(X >= 5)
B.2 <- A %>% anti_join(A.1) %>% slice_sample(n = 2)
#For dplyr < 1.0.0 use sample_n
#B.2 <- A %>% anti_join(A.1) %>% sample_n(2)
A.1
#  SNP  X  Y
#1 rs1  5 aa
#2 rs3  6 aa
#3 rs7 11 ft

B.2
#   SNP   X  Y
#1 rs11 2.2 yh
#2  rs2 1.0 bb
```

`A.1` has all the rows where `X >= 5`. We then use `anti_join` to get all the rows from `A` which is not present in `A.1` and sample 2 rows from it. If you want to combine the two dataframes you can use `bind_rows(A.1, B.2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah !. Your solution also worked, but bouncyball got it first